# How to toggle a view inside of a region in Marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm looking for a better equivalent of:

```
if (view.myRegion.currentView) {
    view.myRegion.reset();
} else {
    var myOtherView = new Marionette.ItemView();
    view.myRegion.show(myOtherView);
}
```

I went through the docs, but didn't find anything similar unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to do this. What is the reason to do it? Would it be better to simply show/hide the view rather than creating/destroying it?

Comment: I have a huge list, which can be expanded to see more details - I don't want to render lots of nodes just to show/hide chosen items later, so I'm creating/destroying views instead

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs - showing a view](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.region.html#showing-a-view) on marionette site, under the **preventDestroy** section,

> If you replace the current view with a new view by calling show,
>   by default it will automatically destroy the previous view.

So perhaps, this could be helpful to you. Region manager would automatically destroy the existing view which is being held by that region and then render the new one.

If there's anything specific that you would like to do at the time of destroy, I believe you can write `onDestroy` callback for that view.

Comment: the logic is a little bit different in my case: if the region has a view inside then reset the region, otherwise show given view inside of the region - like a simple toggle for an accordion

Comment: Oh I see. Even I don't remember if marionette has any functionality which does that. But maybe by using [`beforeSwap` in events raised during show](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.region.html#events-raised-during-show), it could be achieved ?